# How to use C++ struct array for QML ComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, combobox, qml

I've got a struct with two fields, for example:

```
struct testStruct
{
  Q_GADGET
  Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text);
  Q_PROPERTY(QString value MEMBER m_value);

public:
  QString m_text;
  QString m_value;
};
```

There is a `QList<testStruct> m_testStructs` member of my *"AppEngine" class* exposed to QML via
`Q_PROPERTY(QList<testStruct> testStructs READ testStructs NOTIFY testStructsChanged)`.
It is filled like that:

```
testStruct newStruct1, newStruct2;
  newStruct1.m_text = "text1";
  newStruct1.m_value = "value1";
  newStruct2.m_text = "text2";
  newStruct2.m_value = "value2";
  m_testStructs << newStruct1 << newStruct2;
```

So I want to see "text" members in ComboBox list and use "value" members in further operations.

In fact QML ComboBox popup shows me the list of objects names when I set ComboBox's "textRole" property to "text" and "valueRole" to "value", but it does nothing for "currentText" or "currentValue" properties when I click the item, only "currentIndex" changes. Also "displayText" remains blank.

[image]

This is what I get in console when clicking those items:

```
qml: currentIndex: 0; currentText:  ; currentValue: undefined
qml: currentIndex: 1; currentText:  ; currentValue: undefined
```

So I see that ComboBox gets members of struct, but doesn't want to work with them. What should I do to make "currentText" and "currentValue" members of ComboBox work as they should?

Here are all the needed files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "appengine.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  const QUrl url(u"qrc:/qml_testComboBoxStruct/main.qml"_qs);
  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                   &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
      QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
  }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

  //exposing AppEngine class to QML
  AppEngine appEngineObj;
  QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
  context->setContextProperty("AppEngine", &appEngineObj);

  engine.load(url);
  return app.exec();
}
```

my custom class header **AppEngine.h**

```
#ifndef APPENGINE_H
#define APPENGINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

struct testStruct
{
  Q_GADGET
  Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text);
  Q_PROPERTY(QString value MEMBER m_value);

public:
  QString m_text;
  QString m_value;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(testStruct)

class AppEngine : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QList<testStruct> testStructs READ testStructs NOTIFY testStructsChanged);

public:
  explicit AppEngine(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  QList<testStruct> testStructs();

private:
  QList<testStruct> m_testStructs;

signals:
  void testStructsChanged();
};

#endif // APPENGINE_H
```

my custom class cpp file **AppEngine.cpp**

```
#include "appengine.h"

AppEngine::AppEngine(QObject *parent)
  : QObject{parent}
{
  testStruct newStruct1, newStruct2;
  newStruct1.m_text = "text1";
  newStruct1.m_value = "value1";
  newStruct2.m_text = "text2";
  newStruct2.m_value = "value2";
  m_testStructs << newStruct1 << newStruct2;
  qDebug() << "m_testStructs.length():" << m_testStructs.length();
}

QList<testStruct> AppEngine::testStructs()
{
  qDebug() << "testStructs()";
  return m_testStructs;
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("C++ struct to QML ComboBox")

  ComboBox
  {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 180
    height: 30
    id: comboBoxID
    textRole: "text"
    valueRole: "value"
    model: AppEngine.testStructs

    onActivated:
    {
      console.log('currentIndex:', currentIndex, '; currentText:', currentText, ';currentValue:', currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your ComboBox model property can not understands that data structure, If you want to set your model from C++,`it must be a subclass of QAbstractItemModel or a simple list.`

Comment: Is it possible to use c++ struct as QAbstractItemModel sublass? Maybe some macro like Q_GADGET will do the trick?

Comment: Or I simply use `struct testStruct : public QAbstractItemModel` in my struct definition?

Comment: why didn't you handle it in QML? `ListModel` can act like the struct that you create in cpp.

Comment: I have to use C++ struct because in real project it contains much more members, some of them are not even of Qt types. `ListModel` works fine, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked in the `main.qml` model property cant find and understand as you show it is **undefined**.

```
qml: currentIndex: 0; currentText:  ; currentValue: undefined
qml: currentIndex: 1; currentText:  ; currentValue: undefined
```

from [ListView::model property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop)

> The model provides the set of data that is used to create the items in
> the view. Models can be created directly in QML using ListModel,
> ObjectModel, or provided by C++ model classes. **If a C++ model class is
> used, it must be a subclass of QAbstractItemModel or a simple list.**

For example, you can have this :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("C++ struct to QML ComboBox")

    ComboBox
    {
        id: comboBoxID
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 180
        height: 30
        textRole: "text"
        valueRole: "value"
        model: ListModel {
            id : model

            ListElement { text: "text1" ; value : "value1" }
            ListElement { text: "text2" ; value : "value2" }
            ListElement { text: "text3" ; value : "value3" }
            ListElement { text: "text4" ; value : "value4" }


        }

        onActivated:
        {
            console.log('currentIndex:', currentIndex, '; currentText:', currentText, '; currentValue:', currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Because you use QML ListModel if you want to define your model from C++ **it must be a subclass of QAbstractItemModel or a simple list**.

**updated** :

you need to use `QStandardItemModel`  which inherits from `QAbstractItemModel` you **cant inherit from the abstract interface** because of that I use `QStandardItemModel`

**in appengine.h:**

```
#ifndef APPENGINE_H
#define APPENGINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

struct testStruct: public QStandardItemModel
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text);
  Q_PROPERTY(QString value MEMBER m_value);

public:
  QString m_text;
  QString m_value;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(testStruct)

class AppEngine : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QList<testStruct *> testStructs READ testStructs NOTIFY testStructsChanged);

public:
  explicit AppEngine(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  QList<testStruct *> testStructs();

private:
  QList<testStruct *> m_testStructs;

signals:
  void testStructsChanged();
};

#endif // APPENGINE_H
```

**In appengine.cpp**

```
#include "appengine.h"



AppEngine::AppEngine(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    testStruct *newStruct1 = new testStruct;
    testStruct *newStruct2 = new testStruct;


    newStruct1->m_text = "text1";
    newStruct1->m_value = "value1";
    newStruct2->m_text = "text2";
    newStruct2->m_value = "value2";
    m_testStructs << newStruct1 << newStruct2;
    qDebug() << "m_testStructs.length():" << m_testStructs.length();
}

QList<testStruct *> AppEngine::testStructs()
{
    qDebug() << "testStructs()";
    return m_testStructs;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `ListModel` is good if you work only in QML, but in real project I have to use heavy c++ structs to contain data. That is why I'm trying to expose them directly. Otherwise I have to fill QML ListModel with new data from C++ struct and vice versa each time I work with it.

Comment: Is it enough to just write `struct testStruct : public QAbstractItemModel` in my struct definition?

Comment: @Prain I update my answer, `struct testStruct: public QStandardItemModel`.

Comment: I see you changed Q_GADGET to Q_OBJECT and it worked for me as well. But is it necessary to use pointers for objects? Also what is `#include <QSharedPointer>` for?

Comment: @Prain ,No but you should use pointer,  you can use shared pointer too.